# How can I pass a Request.Query/Form object to a custom method as a set of "deserialized" parameters in ASP.Net Core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

**Context**:

In ASP.Net Core 5 controller classes, if I write a GET handler method with custom named parameters, the framework will try to match the Query or Form dictionary values to these parameters. This works with simple types, e.g. strings, numbers and booleans, but also with more complex types, like arrays or custom objects. Example:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostFormData([FromForm] FormModel model) { ... }

public class FormModel {
    // Properties matching the form values
}
```

**Question:**

How can I use this built-in feature of Asp.Net Core with my custom handler methods that are not in a ControllerBase class? With other words, given a `HttpRequest` object and a method signature (`MethodInfo`), how can I invoke the method with the dynamically parsed request parameters, just like ASP.Net does in Controllers?

Code:

```cs
HttpRequest request = ...; // E.g. from a HttpContext
MethodInfo handlerMethod = ...; // A method info from a custom class (not a Controller)

SomeAspNetHelperClass.InvokeMethodWithRequestParameters(request, method); // <-- ???
```

I realize that I could probably implement this on my own, but I know that .Net already has built in tools for it, and I don't feel like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: `handlerMethod.Invoke(classInstance, new object[] { request });`?

Comment: The ASP.NET Core source code is here if you want to try to figure it out yourself: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore

Comment: @PeterCsala That will not work unfortunately. Your code would simply pass the HttpRequest object as a parameter to the method, and that's not what I want.

Comment: @JackA. I could probably write my own implementation of this, even without the dotnet source code, I was just hoping that this part of the code is exposed as public API so I don't have to write my own. It seems like the ASP classes responsible for this are internal classes, so I can't easily access them.

Comment: My point was that you can find such a public API by examining the source code. I've learned more about .NET Core from examining the source code than I ever did by reading the documentation.